# Why does the function not work when using splat in the parameter

Tags: ruby

When you remove the * splat from the parameter the function works fine. However when it's in there the function does not work. Why? See my repl (https://repl.it/LuY8/4)

```
class Hash
  def keys_of(*arguments)
    new_array = []
    self.each do |key, value|
      #puts arguments
      #puts key
      if value == arguments
        new_array << key 
      end
    end
    new_array
  end
end

animals = {"sugar glider"=>"Australia","aye-aye"=> "Madagascar","red-footed tortoise"=>"Panama","kangaroo"=> "Australia","tomato frog"=>"Madagascar","koala"=>"Australia"}

animals.keys_of('Madagascar')
```

Comment: "does not work"?

Comment: see link: https://repl.it/LuY8/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a *varargs* method signature, that is `arguments` will *always* be an array, even for singular values. That means you're getting `['Madagascar']` as your `arguments` and since your keys aren't arrays of a single string, your match fails.

What you probably want is to invert the whole routine and make it more Ruby-like by doing this:

```
def keys_of(*arguments)
  each_with_object([ ]) do |(key, value), a|
    a << key if (arguments.include?(value))
  end
end
```

Problem solved. Ruby has a very rich and featureful core library and [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html) is the real jewel. Familiarize yourself with what it can do before writing your own work-alike methods.

Comment: This handles the `key` => `value` (`Hash#values_at`) but the OP would like `value` => `key`